# How to use the AIO fingerprint?

Tags: javascript, android, ionic-framework, ionic4, fingerprint

I need to use a fingerprint scanner on android and iphone. How to do it right?

I found several options:

1) [try(mhartington Ionic Team)](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/issue-adding-ionic-native-plugin-to-ionic-v3-project/154064/10)

when(In app.module.ts)

```
import { FingerprintAIO } from '@ionic-native/fingerprint-aio'

@NgModule({
  providers: [
...
    FingerprintAIO,
...

  ]
})
```

error:

> index.js:92 Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

[My attempt.](https://github.com/StekolschikovV/ionic-fingerprint-AIO-error)

2) [try (from ionicframework.com)](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/fingerprint-aio)

when(In app.component.ts)

```
import { FingerprintAIO } from '@ionic-native/fingerprint-aio/ngx';
```

error:

> TS2307: Cannot find module '@ionic-native/fingerprint-aio/ngx'.

[My attempt.](https://github.com/StekolschikovV/ionic-fingerprint-AIO-error/tree/v2)

How to use a fingerprint right now?

[3) try](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u2e7uiE9470)

error:

> "SECURITY_EXCEPTION"

or

> "plugin_not_installed"

Answer (score 0):

You should run this cmd

```
npm install @ionic-native/fingerprint-aio@5.22.0-beta-1
```

to add this dependency to your project and fix

```
import { FingerprintAIO } from '@ionic-native/fingerprint-aio/ngx';
```